# Using Javascript to copy content of table cells into new divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, html-table

I'm working on the layout of a well-known store template.  The outer template is completely editable, but the actual product grids are not only hardcoded into the page, but they are also the archaic tabular format.  So, what I thought about doing is using Javascript to extract the contents of the table cells and append them into self-populating divs that I can style into a responsive layout. Then, I would hide the original table.

The table that the page uses is full of content cells and buffer cells and the like, but to simplify it, here is an example of the main items (I used Javascript to add classes all over - which I didn't include in this example - and several ID's, in order to differentiate the different cells.  Here is what my sample looks like.

```
<table id="category-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="titlecell_1">
                <a href="#" id="title_1">Title 1</a>
            </d>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="imagecell_1">
                <a href="#" id="image_1"><img src="image.jpg" /></a>
            </d>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="titlecell_2">
                <a href="#" id="title_2">Title 1</a>
            </d>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="imagecell_2">
                <a href="#" id="image_2"><img src="image.jpg" /></a>
            </d>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
<table>
```

I would like to take the title, the image and their surrounding A tags and plug them into a div to make something like this:

```
<div id="categories">
    <div id="category-div_1">
        <h1><a href="#" id="new-title_1">Title</a></h1>
        <a href="#" id="new-image_1"><img src="image.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="category-div_2">
        <h1><a href="#" id="new-title_2">Title</a></h1>
        <a href="#" id="new-image_2"><img src="image.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is obviously just an example of two items, but this page will have around 16 of them, so this script would obviously need to incrementally add the equivalent of all the cells into new divs.

I have seen different jquery solutions, by using the `clone()`, `replaceWith()` and `replaceAll()` method, for example, but it's all been replacing one item with another.  I would like to replace all of them in their own respective divs.  I don't know if a souped up version of one of those methods is best, or if some sort of index system would work better. I'm just starting to learn Javascript, so trying to put my head around this is overwhelming.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another way:

```
var html = '', i = 0;
$("#category-table td").each(function(){
    if($(this).is("[id^='titlecell']")){
        html += '<div id="category-div_'+(i=i+1)+'">';
        html += '<h1>'+($(this).html().replace('id="title_', 'id="new-title_'))+'</h1>';
    }else if($(this).is("[id^='imagecell']")){
        html += $(this).html().replace('id="image_', 'id="new-image_')+'</div>';   
    }
});
$('<div id="categories"/>').append(html).appendTo('body');
```

EDIT: I forgot about `</div>`. Updated.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u2m8n5nm/2/)

Comment: This seems to plug in everything correctly! Sort of.  Is there a reason for the "else if"? (Again I'm new to Javascript)  It appears that, since the store's table is more complex than my example, every four divs get nested in the other. So, #category-div_2 gets inserted inside #category-div_1 (between the title and image) and so on. Then, it resets at #category-div_5 and the next four divs get nested inside that.  I didn't know if the conditional element had anything to do with that. Every title has an image that goes with it.

Comment: My code is actually for the table you show in the question. The reason why the divs are nested inside, may be because there are more `td` cells in your table than in the example. Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/u2m8n5nm/3/ . You could however show how your table is structured exactly. The `"else if"` statement is to make sure that any other `td` element (if there's any) won't get inside div.

Comment: Understood. And I apologize.  The original table was so convoluted (4 "buffer" cells surrounding each content cell), that I didn't want to overdo it on this page.  Lesson learned.  Between your two different examples, I feel that I will tweak it enough to fit this table.  Thanks a bunch!  When I get to 15 rep, I will be sure to vote this up. :)

Comment: One quick last thing. I think the issue is that I had one td in each tr for my simplified example.  The actual table has 4 title cells in a row, followed by 4 image cells in another row below it.  Then, the process repeats itself.  So, it goes 4 titles and then 4 images, another 4 titles and another four images.  I'm doing different things to tweak your code to match that, but it either wants to nest the divs or create divs for all the titles and then divs for all the images. If it's too complex of an answer, don't worry about it. I'll figure it out.

Comment: Yes, that did it! Except that, when it repeats, it makes the second set four items have the same ID's as the first set. I'll look into it.

Comment: @planetbob , you can also try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/dnqtotx4/ . It's difficult to find a propper (best) solution while I don't see the exact table markup.

Comment: No, need.  That fixed it. And you are correct. I should have put the whole thing in there at once.  But, after I used some javascript to strip out unnecessary cells, your fiddle matched it correctly.  And now it works! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
//create the categories div
var $cat = $('<div/>', {
    id: 'categories'
});

//iterate through all the td's which has id starting with `titlecell_`
$('#category-table td[id^="titlecell_"]').each(function (idx) {
    //create the inner structure
    var id = idx + 1;
    var $div = $('<div/>', {
        id: 'category-div_' + id
    }).appendTo($cat);
    $('<a />', {
        id: 'new-title_' + id,
        href: '#',
        text: $(this).find('a').text()
    }).wrap('<h1 />').parent().appendTo($div);
    $('<a />', {
        id: 'new-image_' + id,
        href: '#'
    }).append($('<img />', {
        src: $(this).parent().next().find('img').attr('src')
    })).appendTo($div);
})

//append the `#categoreis` to the target element
$cat.appendTo('body')
```

```js
//create the categories div
var $cat = $('<div/>', {
  id: 'categories'
});

//iterate through all the td's which has id starting with `titlecell_`
$('#category-table td[id^="titlecell_"]').each(function(idx) {
  //create the inner structure
  var id = idx + 1;
  var $div = $('<div/>', {
    id: 'category-div_' + id
  }).appendTo($cat);
  $('<a />', {
    id: 'new-title_' + id,
    href: '#',
    text: $(this).find('a').text()
  }).wrap('<h1 />').parent().appendTo($div);
  $('<a />', {
    id: 'new-image_' + id,
    href: '#'
  }).append($('<img />', {
    src: $(this).parent().next().find('img').attr('src')
  })).appendTo($div);
})

//append the `#categoreis` to the target element
$cat.appendTo('body')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="category-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="titlecell_1">
        <a href="#" id="title_1">Title 1</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="imagecell_1">
        <a href="#" id="image_1">
          <img src="image.jpg" />
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="titlecell_2">
        <a href="#" id="title_2">Title 1</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="imagecell_2">
        <a href="#" id="image_2">
          <img src="image.jpg" />
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

*Note: Still I wouldn't recommend doing this as this might cause some heavy load on the client if there are lot of data, I would recommend editing the template is possible*

Comment: The two problems I'm having here is that 1) the images are in a different cell (see my example), so I can't use td[id^="titlecell_"] for everything. There is an #imagecell _# to worry about. 2) I used # just as filler for the A tags. Is there a way to scrape the actual url from the old cells to plug into the new div's A tags?

Comment: Also, as an aside, as I said in my original post, I would definitely edit some sort of template to change things... if I could. But the store system won't allow me, and my client wants this system.  On the other hand, these are just the pages that list categories - not products.  So it is literally just 16 titles and images.  No other product info.  I don't think it will affect page load.

Comment: @planetbob sorry, can you tell me again why you can't use `td[id^="titlecell_"]`

Comment: Because the titles are in one cell in one row and the images are in another cell in another row.  The rows have a bunch of other crazy buffer cells and things like that.  So, imaged to use javascript to single out those cells with their own incremental ID's.  However, it doesn't change the fact that the title is one cell and the image is in another.  Believe me, this layout looks c. 2004.

Comment: @planetbob can you update [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/h1kcrudh/1/) to reflect your case

Comment: It is already reflected.  Look at the first td, it has the title and is listed as #titlecell_1.  The second td is listed as #imagecell_1 and has the image in it.  Phillip100's answer seems to address this. I'm checking it out.